# AWS PutRolePolicy Action Restrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to allow a role to call PutRolePolicy to put an inline policy document, but only allow said policy document to create statements for specific actions?

For example, I'd like to allow a role to create and attach policies for resources where the action is ec2:Describe*, but I do NOT want that role to be able to delete the VPC.

Comment: `{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464665038682",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateRole",
        "iam:PutRolePolicy"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`, You can use the above policy.

Comment: that will allow the user to put ANY role policy for any action, unrestricted. In other works, I could put a roll policy with an action that says the user can CreateVpc....which is not what I want

Comment: Wondering the same. Have you found a solution?